# Which phonetic alphabet represents the this sound?

Tags: pronunciation, names, phonetics, vowels

Which phonetic alphabets represents the sound of 'u' in words like 'truck'? My real name includes written 'sam' but it is read as 'sum'. So I want to know what could I write between s _ m to make it clear?

Comment: Thanks. By the way I am new to this site. Can you tell me why do people prefer to Add comment instead of Add Answer. Is it because some questions like these have short answers and short answers get you bad points?

Comment: You took it wrong. I made an account on Stack Exchange recently. I really want to know why one doesn't add answer instead as that will get them more reputation points. Not that points matter to a person though.

Comment: A "letter" or "character" is something like "a" or "ɐ" .  They are **not** alphabets.   An alphabet is a list of all the letters in a language.  "abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz" is one alphabet.  Don't mix up "letter" and "alphabet".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which phonetic alphabets represents the sound of 'u' in words like 'truck'?

It varies from accent to accent.
It might be *open-mid back unrounded vowel*, represented by **/ʌ/** or *near-open central unrounded vowel*, **/ɐ/**.
Most varieties of English use /ʌ/ (also called *STRUT* vowel) in the word 'truck' i.e. /trʌk/.
If your name rhymes with 'sum' then you could transcribe it [ˈsʌm] or [ˈsɐm]

Some other words that have /ʌ/ are luck, gut, cut, strut etc.

Comment: If you are in the United States, very few people will be familiar with the International Phonetic Alphabet, so **/sʌm/** will not help people pronounce your name. It might be better to simply write **(pronounced like "sum")** after your name.

Comment: @AndyB: I assume you wanted to leave this comment on the question..?? I answered what was asked (.."phonetic symbol...")

Comment: Yes, I think your answer was excellent. But because the OP added "to make it clear", I thought it possible that they really wanted to know how best  to communicate the pronunciation of their name to people they came in contact with. And the IPA might be useful in Europe, but less so in the US.